# Polars Selecting all columns without NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I have a dataframe where a number of the columns only consists of NaNs. I am trying to select only the columns in the dataframe where all the values are **not** equal to NaNs using Polars.

I have tried seeing if I could use a similar syntax to how I would proceed in Pandas e.g.

```
df[df.columns[~df.is_null().all()]]
```

However the syntax doesn't translate.
I also know that you can use pl.filter but this only filters rows and not columns based on the criteria's applied within the filter expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this is basically subsetting columns with a boolean mask.

So first let's create some sample data:

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"a": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    "b": [3,4, np.nan, 5], 
    "c": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
})
```

Next we have to get if a column consists completely of NaN Values

```
df.select(pl.all().is_nan().all().is_not())

shape: (1, 3)
┌───────┬──────┬───────┐
│ a     ┆ b    ┆ c     │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ bool  ┆ bool ┆ bool  │
╞═══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ false ┆ true ┆ false │
└───────┴──────┴───────┘
```

To get this DataFrame as iterable we use the row function

```
df.select(pl.all().is_nan().all().is_not()).row(0)

(False, True, False)
```

This we can now use in the bracket notation

```
df[:, df.select(pl.all().is_nan().all().is_not()).row(0)]

shape: (4, 1)
┌─────┐
│ b   │
│ --- │
│ f64 │
╞═════╡
│ 3.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ NaN │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5.0 │
└─────┘
```

Since in general bracket notation is not recommended we can do this also with select: (for looking more concise we use the compress function from itertools)

```
from itertools import compress

df.select(compress(df.columns, df.select(pl.all().is_nan().all().is_not()).row(0)))

shape: (4, 1)
┌─────┐
│ b   │
│ --- │
│ f64 │
╞═════╡
│ 3.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ NaN │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5.0 │
└─────┘
```